# Looking for novel about alien planet adapting to human aggression

Tags: story-identification, novel

Sometime in the late 70'ties or 80'ties I read this novel. It's about a man traveling to a planet where the human colony has a lot of trouble with the indigenous life. The man from the planet accompanying him is very big, muscular, with faster reflexes than ordinary men. This is an adaptation to the conditions on the planet they are traveling to. The conditions on the planet are getting worse all the time.

At the end of the book it is revealed that the local life is reacting telepathically to human aggression, so the situation is becoming worse as the human colonists are becoming more aggressive to save their lives. As the humans realise this they solve the problem by becoming less aggressive. 
Can anyone help me find out which novel this is?

Comment: There is a similar story where the planet sends successive waves of more aggressive creatures to attack colonists. I don't know of this is the story that is being referred to, but unlike Deathworld, it's a short story, not a novel. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student_Body_(short_story), and  [here it is on Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/31815/31815-h/31815-h.htm).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Deathworld](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2127) by Harry Harrison

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld)

> Everything on the planet is deadly to humans. The large animals are strong enough to destroy small vehicles, while the small ones have neurotoxic venom. Even the plants are deadly. All microorganisms consume insufficiently protected tissue as quickly as acids. On top of all this, life evolves so quickly that even Kerk and his Pyrran crew have to be retrained upon their return in order to survive.
>
> Jason now reveals all. Although all life on Pyrrus competes for survival individually, they react collectively to natural disasters. The grubbers, with the assistance of their talkers, have integrated themselves peacefully into the planet's ecosystem, killing only for food or in self-defense. The junkmen, however, think only of killing, and kill everything they can simply because they can. The animals and plants band together against the common threat and cooperate in trying to eliminate them, mutating to better kill humans. Jason proves this to the junkmen, first by having the grubbers safely handle one of the city's ultralethal species, then doing it himself. The city's science director pretends he is handling a training aid, and is able to do the same.